# Html & VB net como baixar uma img com um link dentro de uma Tag?

Tags: html, vb.net

Depois de usar um WebBrowser para logar em um site com o vb, eu quero acessar meu perfil do site, e baixar a img do meu perfil

```
<a href="#" data-target="#profile-photo" data-toggle="modal" class="profile-photo" style="background-image: url("LINK_IMG"); display: block;"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a>
```

Pegar o link dessa parte **background-image: url("LINK_IMG");**

e depois baixar automaticamnete.
É Possivel?

Comment: Bom dia, você quer fazer o download da imagem do seu perfil?

Comment: Sim, isso, e o link que fica nessa linha tem a extensão da imagem .jpg se isso facilita...

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia, abaixo esta um exemplo de como fazer Download de arquivos.

1º - Crie um botão no FrontEnd

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBaixarArq" runat="server" Text="Baixar Arquivo" />
```

2º - Referencie a Namespace abaixo. Coloque no topo da página

```
 Imports System.Net
```

3º - Crie a chamada do evento do clik do botão

```
Protected Sub btnBaixarArq_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBaixarArq.Click
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient

    Try

        Dim urlArquivo As String = "http://ExemploDeSite.com.br/Teste/black.gif"
        Dim caminhoArquivo As String = "D:\PastaTeste"

        client.DownloadFile(urlArquivo, caminhoArquivo)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Erro ao fazer Download!")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Tipo isso, mas a url eu quero pegar do background-image: url("LINK_IMG.jpg");